# how to get the child attributes from xml with c#

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to display the data from xml file. I cant get the attributes for the child elements (category and cell). i get System.NullReferenceException error. How can i display the child elements?

This is some part from the xml

```
<group number="3704542" text="3704542" varName="BATCH_NO">
  <category number="1" text="1">
    <dimension axis="column" text="Variables">
      <category label="Batch Run" text="Batch Run" varName="BATCH_RUN_ID" variable="true">
        <cell number="4202" text="4202" varName="BATCH_RUN_ID"/>
      </category>
      <category label="Application" text="Application" varName="APP_ID" variable="true">
        <cell label="Calibration" number="101" text="Calibration" varName="APP_ID"/>
      </category>
  </dimension>
  </category>
</group>
```

this is the c# code

```
private void GetXMLData1()
{
    try
    {
        XNamespace ns = "http://www.ibm.com/software/analytics/spss/xml/oms";
        XDocument testXML = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\byilmaz\Desktop\SPSS_SITE\test.xml");

        var cats = from cat in testXML.Descendants(ns + "dimension").Where
                   (cat => (string)cat.Attribute("axis") == "column" && (string)cat.Attribute("text") == "Variables")

                   select new
                       {
                           groupName = cat.Parent.Parent.Attribute("number").Value,
                           catId = cat.Parent.Attribute("number").Value,
                           //catName = cat.Element("category").Attribute("label").Value,
                       };

        foreach (var cat in cats)
        {
            xmlTitle.Text += "Group Name: " + cat.groupName + " and Cat Id: " + cat.catId + "</br>";
            //xmlTitle.Text += "Cat Name: " + cat.catName + " </br>";
        }

    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        throw (err);
    }
}
```

and output is:

### [image]

When i take the comment line off from the below code, i get System.NullReferenceException error.

```
//catName = cat.Element("category").Attribute("label").Value,
```

Comment: Maybe that particular node doesn't have a label attribute set? Try checking for null before accessing .Value property.

Comment: I tested your code and it [works just fine](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EHdQpV) (without the namespace) (or, at least it does not throw any exceptions). Can you add additional information? Can you doublecheck that it is the correct xml?

Comment: oh, nooo. the problem is the namespace